# is it possible to change URL dynamically inMPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to stream movie from the internet. And now my first application start to look nice :) BUT :) I have 4 URLs to stream (different movies), and I wan't when I tap to the movie to stop current movie and play another from another URL. Like changing channels on TV. I know how to catch tap, but I don't know how to change URL and start to play movie from that URL (like TV), any help?
I have used this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html#comment-33682) to make application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `setContentURL` is the function you're looking for.  See:
[Apple Documentation on MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW33)

Comment: How this is possible I have object: mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL]; And when I try to call that method: [mp setContentURL:newUrl]; There is no such method?

Comment: Now I added this: [mp contentURL:newStreamLocation]; but after this line I get SIGABRT error.

Comment: Now I find that many things missing. I try mp.useApplicationAudioSession but there is no that property.

Answer (score 0):

use [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:newUrl] to show the next video/movie. It is given in the Apple Documentation on MPMoviePlayerController. :)